# How to set urls with port of StubRunner from spring-cloud-contract in spring-cloud-gateway contract tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway, spring-cloud-contract

I have a spring cloud gateway application which routes requests to another service. Another service defines contracts which are imported as stubs by spring cloud gateway application in tests.

Now I would like to have contract tests in my gateway that will consume the stubs of another service. The problem is that I do not know how to inject the `StubRunnerPort` as property/environment so it can be picked by my configuration class and configure the routes  accordingly :

Api gateway routes configuration

```
@Configuration
class GatewayConfig {

    
    @Value("${subscriptions.url}")
    private String subscriptionsUrl;

    @Autowired
    private TokenRelayGatewayFilterFactory tokenFilterFactory;

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http.csrf(ServerHttpSecurity.CsrfSpec::disable);
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    RouteLocator routeLocator(final RouteLocatorBuilder routeLocatorBuilder) {
        return routeLocatorBuilder.routes()
                .route("subscriptions", subscriptionsRoute())
                .build();
    }

    private Function<PredicateSpec, Buildable<Route>> subscriptionsRoute() {
        return spec -> spec
                .path("/subscriptions/**")
                .filters(s -> s.filter(tokenFilterFactory.apply()).prefixPath("/v1"))
                .uri(subscriptionsUrl);
    }

}
```

And the test class :

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, classes = {PnApiGatewayApp.class})
@AutoConfigureStubRunner(ids = "io.mkrzywanski:subscription-app:+:stubs", stubsMode = StubRunnerProperties.StubsMode.CLASSPATH)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class SubscriptionSpec {

    private WebTestClient webClient;

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    @StubRunnerPort("io.mkrzywanski:subscription-app")
    private int stubRunnerPort;

    @Autowired
    ConfigurableEnvironment environment;

    @BeforeEach
    void setup() {
        String baseUri = "http://localhost:" + port;
        this.webClient = WebTestClient.bindToServer()
                .responseTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
                .baseUrl(baseUri).build();
    }

    @Test
    void  test() {
        String body = "{\"userId\":\"22e90bbd-7399-468a-9b76-cf050ff16c63\",\"itemSet\":[{\"value\":\" Rainbow Six\"}]}";
        var response = webClient.post()
                .uri("/subscriptions")
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer xxx")
                .header("Content-type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .bodyValue(body)
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isCreated()
                .expectBody(String.class)
                .value(Matchers.equalTo("{\"subscriptionId : \"6d692849-58fd-439b-bb2c-50a5d3669fa9\"\"}"));
    }
```

Ideally I would like to have `subscriptions.url` property set **after** stub runner is configured but **before** my gateway configuration is picked by Spring so that url redirects will work.

I have already tried to use `ApplicationContextInitializer` but it seems that StubRunnerPort is not configured yet, when instance of initializer is launched.

So the question is - how to get stub runner port and use it to inject it into other services url, so that gateway would route the requests to the stub runner in tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution 1

This can be achieved by using `application-test.yml` file with defined url property that makes use of substitution. `application-test.yml` file. The approach is described [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/reference/html/project-features.html#features-stub-runner-rule-spring) :

```
subscriptions:
  url: http://localhost:${stubrunner.runningstubs.io.mkrzywanski.subscription-app.port}
```

Here `stubrunner.runningstubs.io.mkrzywanski.subscription-app.port` will be available as Stub port so it can be substituted. No configuration changes are reuqired.

## Solution 2 (requires more code)

I made it work by creating a test configuration which extends configuration that contains url properties and `RouteLocator` configuration and has a dependency on `batchStubRunner` bean :

```
@DependsOn("batchStubRunner")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Import(LoggingFilter.class)
class GatewayTestConfig extends GatewayConfig implements InitializingBean {

    @Autowired
    ConfigurableEnvironment environment;

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        this.subscriptionsUrl = "http://localhost:" + environment.getProperty("stubrunner.runningstubs.io.mkrzywanski.subscription-app.port");
    }
}
```

The key points here are :

- the configuration is run only after `batchStubRunner` bean is available so the port of StrubRunner can be found in the `environment`
- The configuration implements `InitializingBean` so I am able to override the `subscriptionsUrl` which is now `protected` in parent configuration
- After `subscriptionsUrl` is overriden - it can be used to configure `RouteLocator` bean from parent configuration.

The test looks like this now :

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, classes = {GatewayTestConfig.class})
@AutoConfigureStubRunner(ids = "io.mkrzywanski:subscription-app:+:stubs", stubsMode = StubRunnerProperties.StubsMode.CLASSPATH)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class SubscriptionSpec {

    private WebTestClient webClient;

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    @BeforeEach
    void setup() {
        String baseUri = "http://localhost:" + port;
        this.webClient = WebTestClient.bindToServer()
                .responseTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
                .baseUrl(baseUri).build();
    }

    @Test
    void shouldRouteToSubscriptions() {

        String body = "{\"userId\":\"22e90bbd-7399-468a-9b76-cf050ff16c63\",\"itemSet\":[{\"value\":\"Rainbow Six\"}]}";
        webClient.post()
                .uri("/subscriptions")
                .header("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer xxx")
                .header("Content-type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .bodyValue(body)
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isCreated()
                .expectBody()
                .jsonPath("$.subscriptionId").exists()
                .jsonPath("$.subscriptionId").value(IsUUID.UUID());
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for Spring Boot 2.x for me. But it somehow does not with Spring Boot 3.x anymore.

Comment: For Spring Boot 3.x

`spring.cloud.openfeign.lazy-attributes-resolution=true` did the trick for me